# Migrating ASP web site into Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, asp-classic, sharepoint-2007, migration

I need to migrate a ASP legacy web application into MOSS 2007. Is there any tool that can be used for migration? if so please specify?

Comment: This question doesn't even make sense on the face of it. There must be some information you've left out, like why would you think there's any similarity between Classic ASP and SharePoint. Why does this even look like it makes any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I've ever heard of. I'm afraid you'll have to rebuild. It depends on what the ASP app does though; SharePoint may cover its features out of the box.
An a best-case scenario you might be able to copy some documents in and be done with it.

Of course classic ASP can be made to work on a SharePoint server and you can always frame the app in in an IFrame.